# Update from 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 problem

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg

Whenever I try to run:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

It shows:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You need to use `sudo` to elevate your privileges

Comment: Please use appropriate flags, you've tagged 14.04 which is not related to the release in your heading, and you've tagged 3 different *flavors* which just leads to questions & reduces trust in your provided detail (desktops are usually mutually exclusive, esp. with servers you also tagged).

Comment: This, and Chromium in the title is not part of the question either.

Answer (score 0):

Precede your command with `sudo`, like so:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This will grant you the privileges required to run the `apt` command.